# Order by clause in MySQL is not working inside a foreach loop

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to get the profiles names which are assigned to a specific subcategory 
with id=9. When I run the code below, I get the profiles that I want but for some 
reason the ORDER BY clause in the foreach loop doesn't sort them by their name 
alphabetically. Instead they are ordered in the same way they are ordered inside the 
'profiles' field in 'subcategories' table (the IDs for the profiles are comma separated). 
For example if in subcategories['profiles'] I have ',5,1,2' the profiles names will be displayed
in the following order:

1. Profile with ID=5
2. Profile with ID=1
3. Profile with ID=2

I'm using the explode() function to get the ID for each profile inside the 'subcategory' 
table and then use that ID to retrieve their information from the 'profile' table using 
a query inside the foreach loop.

Am I missing anything here? Thanks for your help.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$subcategories=mysql_query("select * from subcategories where id='9'");

while ($subcategories = mysql_fetch_array($subcategories)) 

{
 $profiles = $subcategories['profiles'];
 $profiles = explode(',', $profiles);

       foreach ($profiles as $p)
       {
         $all_places = mysql_query("select * from profile where id='$p' and active='1' order by name asc");

           while ($profile = mysql_fetch_array($all_places)) 
           {

               echo $profile['name'];                   

           }

       }

}
?>
```

Comment: Does it work fine without the `ORDER BY` clause (If it is excluded)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the reason why your results do not order by name is because you are retrieving every profile with a new SQL query in your foreach loop for $profiles. So effectively in your scenario, you will end up with 3 SQL queries that returns 1 profile each. Hence, when the "order by" clause is declared, it orders by name within each query, which only contains 1 result each.

does using an IN statement work for you? Eg.

```
    <?php
$subcategories=mysql_query("select * from subcategories where id='9'");

while ($subcategories = mysql_fetch_array($subcategories)) 

{

//i assume $subcategories['profiles'] are integers separated by comma as mentioned
 $profiles = $subcategories['profiles'];

                 $all_places = mysql_query("select * from profile where id IN ($profiles) and active='1' order by name asc");

                     while ($profile = mysql_fetch_array($all_places)) 
                     {

                       echo $profile['name'];                   

                     }

}
?>
```

Comment: I just figured out another way to do this. Instead of selecting the profile IDs from the subcategories table, I select all profiles which have that subcategory ID, using LIKE in mysql statement. $subcategories='9';
    $subcategories1=mysql_query("select * from profile where subcategories LIKE '%$subcategories%' AND active='1' order by name asc");I also removed the inner foreach and while loops since they were no longer needed. It seems to work fine now, thanks.

Comment: It seems to work fine now, except a small problem: if I have subcategory ids 9 and 19 the above query will return both. Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: Problem solved, I tried what you suggested and it worked. I just needed to remove the first comma from $profiles string since it was causing a problem. Thanks for your help!